# Недостающие биты в последний блок разбиения файла, шифр TEA

Tags: c, шифрование

Пишу реализацию блочного алгоритма шифрования TEA для файлов. Нужно разбить файл на блоки по 64 бита, причем последний блок при необходимости добить до кратности в 64-бит, установив недостающие байты в 0x01. Вопрос: как проверить блок на кратность и добить эти недостающие байты?

```
FILE *openFile, *resultFile;
    char buffer[8], key[8] = "01234567";
    if ((openFile = fopen("c:/dev/encoding/test.xlsx", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((resultFile = fopen("c:/dev/encoding/test.enc", "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, openFile);
    do {
        encrypt(buffer, key); 
        if ((fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, resultFile)) != 8) {
            printf("Fatal Error writing output file!!!\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, openFile);
    } while (!feof(openFile));
    fclose(openFile);
    fclose(resultFile);
```

Comment: Совершенно не понятна суть вопроса. Кто вам мешает читать файлы и записывать блоками по 64 бита?

Comment: fread возвращает кол-во реально прочитанных байт и если оно вдруг меньше 8 - то дополнять

Comment: @Mike, а как проверить? Извините, я в Си новичок.

Comment: if ((fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, openFile)) != 8) такая проверка будет правильной?

Comment: ну я бы все таки в переменную сохранил предварительно, вам же еще дополнять. т.е. дописывать 8-длина байт

Comment: С таким уровнем криптографию лучше не писать свою, а брать готовую: меньше шансов напортачить где-нибудь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, вот что получилось. Теперь, правда, не соответствует заголовку темы. Кидаю код всего файла, вдруг кому пригодится, тем более в интернетах такого не нашел. Если есть еще способы, прошу, напишите.

```
#include "tea.h"

void main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *srcFile, *resultFile;

    if ((srcFile = fopen("c:/dev/encoding/test.xlsx", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((resultFile = fopen("c:/dev/encoding/test.enc", "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    encodeFile(srcFile, resultFile, "01234567");

    fclose(srcFile);
    fclose(resultFile);

    if ((srcFile = fopen("c:/dev/encoding/test.enc", "rb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((resultFile = fopen("c:/dev/encoding/res.xlsx", "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    decodeFile(srcFile, resultFile, "01234567");

    fclose(srcFile);
    fclose(resultFile);
    return 0;
}

void encodeFile(FILE* srcFile, FILE* resultFile, uint32_t* key){
    printf("Start encoding\n");
    fseek(srcFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(srcFile);
    fseek(srcFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    if ((fwrite(&size, sizeof(long), 1, resultFile)) != 1) {
        printf("Fatal Error writing output file!!!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char buffer[8];
    while (!feof(srcFile)) {
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, srcFile);
        encrypt(buffer, key);
        if ((fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, resultFile)) != 8) {
            printf("Fatal Error writing output file!!!\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    printf("Encoding complete\n");
}

void decodeFile(FILE* srcFile, FILE* resultFile, uint32_t* key){
    printf("Start decoding\n");
    char buffer[8];
    long size;
    fread(&size, sizeof(long), 1, srcFile);
    printf("%i\n", size);
    for (size; size > 8; size -= 8){
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, srcFile);
        decrypt(buffer, key);
        if ((fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, resultFile)) != 8) {
            printf("Fatal Error writing output file!!!\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 8, srcFile);
    decrypt(buffer, key);
    if ((fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), size, resultFile)) != size) {
        printf("Fatal Error writing output file!!!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Decoding complete\n");
}

void encrypt(uint32_t* v, uint32_t* k){
    /* set up */
    uint32_t v0 = v[0];
    uint32_t v1 = v[1];
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    uint32_t i;

    /* a key schedule constant */
    uint32_t delta = 0x9e3779b9;

    /* cache key */
    uint32_t k0 = k[0];
    uint32_t k1 = k[1];
    uint32_t k2 = k[2];
    uint32_t k3 = k[3];

    /* basic cycle start */
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        sum += delta;
        v0 += ((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >> 5) + k1);
        v1 += ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >> 5) + k3);
    }
    /* end cycle */

    v[0] = v0;
    v[1] = v1;
}

void decrypt(uint32_t* v, uint32_t* k){
    /* set up */
    uint32_t v0 = v[0];
    uint32_t v1 = v[1];
    uint32_t sum = 0xC6EF3720;
    uint32_t i;

    /* a key schedule constant */
    uint32_t delta = 0x9e3779b9;

    /* cache key */
    uint32_t k0 = k[0];
    uint32_t k1 = k[1];
    uint32_t k2 = k[2];
    uint32_t k3 = k[3];

    /* basic cycle start */
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        v1 -= ((v0 << 4) + k2) ^ (v0 + sum) ^ ((v0 >> 5) + k3);
        v0 -= ((v1 << 4) + k0) ^ (v1 + sum) ^ ((v1 >> 5) + k1);
        sum -= delta;
    }
    /* end cycle */

    v[0] = v0;
    v[1] = v1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем проверять? просто перед чтением в буфер проинициализируйте его заданным значением. Те байты буфера, которым не хватит байтов из файла, так и останутся с этим значением...

Comment: К сожалению, я не понял, что вы имеете в виду. Дело в том, что программа работает, вот только в конце расшифрованного файла появляются лишние символы.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что перед fread в buffer следует поместить 8 байтов 0x01. Если прочитается 8 байтов, все они перезапишутся, если меньше, то остальные так и останутся 0x01.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Поправил пост. Но код все равно работает неправильно. Как теперь избавиться от этих лишних байт при расшифровке?

Comment: Только сохраняя где-то исходный размер данных (либо иную информацию о размере данных). Иначе нет возможности, видя конечные байты 0x01, определить, являются они значащими или дополненными.

Comment: Как же тогда зашифровывать/расшифровывать? По заданию у меня есть только файл и ключ, внятных примеров работы TEA с файлами на Си в интернете не нашел.

Comment: Да просто зарезервируй последний блок под размер зашифрованных данных. И записывай размер туда, тупо без всякого шифрования и без дополнения этими 0x01.

Comment: Как я им воспользуюсь-то, если он будет в конце?

Comment: Ну пусть будет в начале, какая нафиг разница?

Comment: Я просто лишь второй день пишу на чистом Си, поэтому не знаю как переставить указатель на начало файла, имея размер в байтах.

Comment: Я на нём вообще не пишу - и что? А на начало файла указатель при открытии на чтение устанавливается самостоятельно.